# How to move water/lava in Terraria

Tags: terraria

I am wondering how to move water and lava in Terraria.

Comment: Moving and redirecting are not really the same thing. This is not a duplicate IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [buckets](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bucket) to move small quantities of liquids, as well as [pumps](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pump) and gravity for large stores of liquids (liquids will flow down to the lowest depth they can reach, then spread equally along the horizontal axis).

Comment: once you have a small amount of liquid in a bucket you can make more by using a Generator. See also youtube for videos.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a pump, But it depends how far you want to carry the water/lava.pumps  do have to be connected with wire but i think the limit of blocks you can place it is 1000. hope this helps!